# How do I place the seat back 20 cm with a full suspension bike?

Tags: saddle, seatpost

[image]

[image]

Here are 2 ideas for a makeshift design. The first one is no not that good. The second idea seems more doable using 2 heavy duty seatpost attached luggage racks.

The seatpost is 33mm diameter, dunno if that the official size but it's as close as I could measure it. The seat is great. The bike is aluminium alloy so I wish to keep it light.

Is there a pro solution to putting the seat back like this?

Comment: Why do you need that amount of adjustment ? The seat rails should provide more than enough adjustment for a decent fitting bike. I wouldn't want to sit on anything that would potentially skewer my crown jewels in an accident or a bolt snapping.

Comment: You can buy seatposts with various amounts of setback. But generally you shouldn’t need much setback. Keep in mind that the most important thing on a bike (apart from safety) is seating position in regard to your legs. Never compensate for a short frame by sliding the saddle backwards.

Comment: BTW this is a good question and I have upvoted it, despite being a bad idea in my opinion.  Thank you for describing clearly your idea.

Comment: @Criggie i suppose it's useful to have something that says DON'T DO THIS!

Comment: This is going to make your suspension not operate in the way it was designed. No good.

Comment: Are you sure that every single part of this contraption is strong enough? Can your seat tube handle that much torque? Also, the steerer clamp area of a stem is 28.6mm, which really shouldn’t be spread to fit around a 33mm seatpost.

Comment: @MaplePanda I know it's not going to work, I'm asking for a better solution. I think I found it. Heavy duty seat clamped luggage rack.

Comment: The seatpost clamped luggage racks have maximum loads much, much less than a person's weight. Using one will put a huge bending load on the seat post.

Comment: Even if you find a solution which doesn’t break the seat post or frame or back wheel, it will be extremely back-heavy. You’ll have very little weight and grip on the front wheel which is dangerous. It’s like riding on your luggage rack.

Comment: @Michael riding rear-heavy is actually not dangerous at all, on the contrary it's the safest way of tackling very steep descents. (But this shouldn't be done with a far-back saddle, but instead a dropper post to get the saddle out of the way completely!) Only, a slack seat angle makes pedalling inefficient and leads you to inadvertently wheelie on any ascent.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In the front is the second heaviest thing other than me on the bike, it's the battery pack, which is right over the front wheel. Also, the center of the seat once set back will be aligned horizontally with the front of the rear wheel.

Comment: @EricHuelin that however is another bad idea. The battery should be placed as low and central as possible. Over the front wheel is about the worst place you can put it.

Comment: Please get rid of the motor. Hurting yourself is okay, but with motorized bike it's too easy to hurt others.

Comment: This whole thread looks like a massive case of the XY problem

Comment: I think I understand now. You have a custom frame that requires that much setback in order to get the proper pedaling position, right? If so, it’s completely up to you whether or not your frame can handle the leverage. If you can make a custom frame, surely a custom seatpost that doesn’t require bolting two stems together or something isn’t too far out of the question.

Comment: @MaplePanda I can make custom frames but I'm a living room mechanic, I have no area not even a balcony to do anything like welding so all I can do is cut metal or bolt things together.

Comment: @user622505 it's a common theme that the users who ask about homemade e-bikes really want a motorbike, and preferably one they're somehow allowed to ride drunk and without helmet, insurance or driver's license or at least significantly cheaper than real motorcycle. It never occurs to them that those don't exist for a reason.

Comment: @ojs I just bought my first factory made E-Bike instead of making my own. I rode motorcycles and scooters for decades and for the last 5 years using my own home made E-Bikes without incident so what are you talking about me hurting others?

Comment: @EricHuelin Your best bet is to find a way to make a properly designed custom seatpost. Perhaps there is a metal fabricator near you that can help you weld or do whatever other metalworking techniques end up being required. Bolting together random components like stems and rack mounts and hoping they hold up is a bad idea.

Answer (score 31):

The only safe answer is to buy a bigger bike frame.

When your adaptor fails, you will descend rapidly onto the rear wheel.
The remaining original seatpost has an excellent chance of tearing your chest open, and impaling your head up through the jawbone.

While this is definitely creative, its absolutely not the right answer.

**Buy a bigger bike frame.**

---

If you're under 20, then there's a good chance you're still growing.  Even more reason to buy a larger frame bike.

Comment: You forgot to mention the part that's likely to matter the most to a lot of younger guys: *first* it destroys the family jewels. Then if you're particularly unfortunate, it might not kill you...

Comment: SUCH A BUNCH OF CYNICAL NAYSAYERS. I've been using a layback seatpost for years never had any trouble at all for my custom bike builds, the only problem, 1 I'm using the only one I have it and it's just made for classic seatpost sizes with the narrowing tip. I'll take the hint as to have nothing modern to purchase and build my own.

Comment: @EricHuelin a layback seatpost is quite different from your mockup picture.  For a start, a seatpost is one piece of metal, whereas the image suggests two stems mounted mirrored.   All your weight is on 2 or 4 critical bolts, which are probably M5x0.8 and not really capable of supporting an adult body weight in tension.  When used as a stem, these bolts and threads are under shear force.

Comment: @Criggie I'm asking for a professional idea that is better than mine, that was the question. People who say get a bigger bike don't understand why I want a layback setup, it's for when I stop, I hate having to tip over and landing on one foot. I want both feet to rest on the ground when I stop. My solution: To buy 2 heavy duty seatpost attached luggage racks cut so one is attached to the seat post normally with no seat the other rack is facing the other way to attach the seat layback. Bolted on top of each other, the back of the luggage rack has a span that is bolted to the bike frame.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. It's a bad idea and don't come to blame us when it fails, but at least the racks are less likely to snap in the middle and the remaining stub to stab you in the crotch.

Comment: @Eric Huelin You’re talking about 200ft•lb of torque or greater on the rack-to-seatpost joint, which will almost certainly break it. Running such a large amount of setback is also biomechanically sub-optimal. Just learn to move your butt forwards off the saddle and hovering over the top tube before stopping. Full squish MTBs usually lack the necessary rack mounting holes anyways on the dropouts, and the frame is not guaranteed to be strong enough to handle clamped on ones.

Comment: @EricHuelin How does moving the seat back at the same height help your feet reach the ground?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I never said it would be at the same height. I can lower the seat height by placing it further back from the pedals. At the original location I would need to place the seat to its maximum allowable elevation for a comfortable pedal stroke. But I want the comfort of stopping without getting off the seat or tilt sideways or hope for an elevation that I can rest my foot on.

Comment: @EricHuelin Please add a diagram to your question to show the allowable range of saddle positions with respect to the road. It seems that we are not understanding the geometry you are seeking, so a picture could help us. Maybe a recumbent (possibly tricycle) geometry would be ideal for you?

Comment: @EricHuelin sounds like a "crank forward" frame design, where the pedals are in front of the knees.  Something like https://bicycleman.com/wp-content/uploads/RANS-Fusion-blue.jpg ?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Your ideal saddle height revolves around the BB. Putting the saddle lower but farther back achieves the same linear distance between saddle and BB as a higher-but-further-forwards position. Of course, putting the saddle so far back is the wrong position for optimal power generation.

Comment: Since there is no such thing as "crank forward" bike with rear wheel suspension. I figured it was easier to move the seat back with a full suspension E-bike.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: This looks as a potential nominee for the next Darwin Award!

Answer (score 8):

The classic solution is banana seat and sissy bars. You'll lose the rear suspension, but the chances are that it's not going to work anyway because you'd be sitting way more back than what the suspension was designed for.

Edit: [Looks like suspension sissy bars do exist](https://www.bicycledesigner.com/bike-parts/bicycle-sissybar/cuda-suspension-sissybar---chrome.html). It's going to be an interesting problem to balance the frame and seat suspension.

Comment: Excellent point - it would be something like riding a bicycle while sitting on its parcel rack.

Comment: When I was 7, sitting on the rack and pulling off awesome wheelies was the second best thing after Nintendo.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple, pro solution to this and it is have a framebuilder make you a seatpost that can do this.

A simple iteration would be a bunch of segments of chromoly tubes, which may need the part that goes in the frame to be turned, and then have the last segment be a 22.2mm one such that it can take a cheap saddle clamp. A more sophisticated version could have guts transplanted from another seatpost.

There is an open question with all of this whether your frame can handle this kind of leverage at the seatpost opening without flaring open. My guess is probably not, and there's no way to solve that problem. There are bikes that are designed to have much more setback than others, i.e. most Electras and their many copies, so you are not playing in a new sandbox here, but those frames have slacker seattubes to keep the aforementioned leverage down.

Comment: I investigated these slacker seatubes and beach cruisers, all you get is hard tails and fixies. I have hills and bad roads that my legs and my pelvis can't handle. So I went for the closest I could find to my criteria list I found nothing, except this one bike but it was just a few inches off my ideal bike.